# How to Pass the data given in UITextField to another variable on another class

Tags: swift, xcode

So i have a UITextField named apiTextField and a function of the saveButton :

func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
}
I want when the user writes to the UITextField and press the saveButton that text the user wrote be passed to a variable which is called var baseURL:String? in another class.

I didn't find anything related to UITextField so i decided to make this question, another similar one is 10 years old!.

Comment: You can inject a dependency class in your main class, and then access it’s properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var anotherClass = AnotherClass()

func saveButton(_ sender: Any) { 
    guard let text = apiTextField.text, !text.isEmpty else { return }
    anotherClass.baseURL = text
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! , this one worked as a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).